# Can I create custom pivot table name using another M:M entity?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm still thinking is there a ways how can I create a custom pivot table name? Because I created a **documents** and **users** table has a many to many relationship with **document_user** which is my **pivot table** and this table was created for received document that user created. And I'm planning to create a another pivot table for **document** and **user** this table was for sent documents so I can have history. See my code below.

**create_document_user_table**

```
public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('document_user',function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('document_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('document_id')->references('id')->on('documents')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unsignedInteger('sender_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('sender_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->dateTime('dateReceived')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        $table->timestamp('dateModified')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    });
 }
```

**documents_table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('documents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**users_table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('middle_name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('remember_token');

        $table->integer('role_permission_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('role_permission_id')->references('id')->on('roles_permissions_dt')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This works well inserting records to my pivot table. What I'm planning to achieve is every-time I inserted a records for **documents** this will inserted too in my custom pivot table not only in my **document_user** pivot table. Any help would appreciated! Thanks for your info or tips.

**UPDATE**

@Mina thanks for the tips that you given but actually this is my insert or save for my pivot table. How can I inserted this in my revisions table?

**DocumentController**

```
public function postDocuments(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,
    [
        'title' => 'required|regex:/(^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$)+/|max:255',
        'content' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'recipient_id' => 'required',
    ]);     


    $document = new Document();
                                //Request in the form
    $document->title = $request->title;
    $document->content = $request->content;
    $document->category_id = $request->category_id;

    $document->save();
    $user = Auth::user();

    foreach($request->recipient_id as $recipientId)
    {
        $document->recipients()->sync([ $recipientId => ['sender_id' => $user->id]],false );
    }

    return redirect()->back();  
}
```

Comment: why another pivot table, it's a relation to the document directly.

Comment: @MinaAbadir Because what I did I need a history of created and received documents for each user. That's why I created a M:M relationship.

Comment: Can one document be created by many users?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes it can be created by many users.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need another pivot table. You need a table like that:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('revisions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('document_id')->unsigned();
        //Rest of table structure

        $table->foreign('document_id')->references('id')->on('document_user')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

When you need to create a new Revision:

```
$document = new Document;
//add $document attributes
$user->documents()->save($document);

$document->recipients->each(function($recipient){
      $id = $recipient->pivot->id;
      Revision::create(['document_id'=>$id]);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Is `Revision` is my Model? Am I right? What if I already inserted a values in my `document_user` how can I inserted this in my 1:M?

Comment: use Revision is a model sorry for not mentioning it. You can insert it as I have mentioned. Get the new record id through a find statement on the collection, then the id using the pivot attribute, I will add more clarification.

Comment: I'm gonna try your tips and code now. Can I update you?

Comment: How can I make a Model for my `document_user` table? I still don't have an idea.

Comment: You don't need that, all you need is the pivot table id, and as mentioned in the answer you can get it through the pivot table.

Comment: Also in my `Revision` model I don't need to create a function that has a relationship with my pivot table? Aside from your code why you create a new instance of Document Model?

Comment: You don't really need the relationship, it won't be of much benefit, as your document_user relevant model does not reflect a functional specs. However if you want to create it, the system allows that. I have created a new Document for example completeness not something of real value actually.

Comment: Did you already tried this? I updated my post can you please see thanks!

Comment: recipient here is the User?

Comment: recipient here is the user_id and sender here is the sender_id. I just loop all the recipient in my foreach so the user can have a list of recipients except the current user that logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your pivot tables as you like.

> As mentioned previously, to determine the table name of the
>   relationship's joining table, Eloquent will join the two related model
>   names in alphabetical order. However, you are free to override this
>   convention. You may do so by passing a second argument to the
>   belongsToMany method:
>
> `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_roles');`

([Eloquent: Relationships #Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many))

In your case you would need to define the relations like this:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    // other stuff

    createdDocuments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Document', 'document_user_created');
    }

    sentDocuments() // or receivedDocuments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Document', 'document_user_sent');
    }

    // other stuff
}


class Document extends Model
{
    // other stuff

    createdByUsers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'document_user_created');
    }

    sentToUsers() // or sentFromUsers() or whatever it does mean
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'document_user_sent');
    }

    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: I think this will not work in the second argument because it follows the rules. Already tried this but I'm able to insert.

Comment: What exactly is not working? What did you try to insert?

Comment: What I mean if I didn't follow the follow the rules of Laravel. I just can't insert the values in my pivot table.

Comment: Did you try `$document->sentToUsers()->attach($request->recipient_id);`?